# Using PBR or similar for an IP SLA for a C1111-8P-TLELA with a dynamic Cellular WAN IP

Tags: cisco, failover, ios-xe, lte

I am trying to get 4G Failover working on a Cisco C1111-8P-LTELA router. I have a known working solution that I usually use with IP SLA, and a local PBR route-map that forces traffic out of the correct interface depending on the source IP. **The problem in this case is that I don't know the WAN IP of the LTE interface as it's dynamic.**

Ultimately my question is: **How can I get IP SLA traffic to correctly send out the desired source interface, regardless of what the current default route is, when the source IP is dynamic?**

I can't figure out a way to match traffic sourced from a dynamic IP or a particular egress interface, so it doesn't seem like PBR is an option?

Here's the config I would normally use - this will force traffic for each WAN's source IP out of the correct interface, regardless of which WAN is currently active, allowing IP SLA for both WANs to always work.

Previously our 4G was connected via ethernet to an external dongle, so we were able to have a static IP on both WAN interfaces, but now with this LTE router, the dynamic 4G address, this doesn't work right now, and I am not sure how else to approach it.

### Things I've tried

- I tried adding a clause to the PBR to match on the interface name, but this doesn't work as it seems to match all traffic, including LAN traffic, and force it over 4G which breaks my local connection to the router, and takes the fibre (primary WAN) offline. It's far too broad of a match.

  ```
    route-map PBR-SRC-ADDR permit 20
     description Route traffic with source interface of Cellular0/2/0 to interface Cellular0/2/0 regardless of default route.
    match interface Cellular0/2/0
    set interface Cellular0/2/0
    exit
  ```
- I considered having the 4G IP SLA pinging a different IP address, with a /32 that *always* routes through Cellular0/2/0. The problem is I don't think it's acceptable to be forcing all traffic for any destination out 4G when we have a perfectly usable fibre WAN 99% of the time. This could end up causing performance issues for users.

### Config

```
! This is the LTE 4G Interface - usually this would be just an Ethernet WAN with a static IP but now it is negotiated.
interface Cellular0/2/0
 ip address negotiated
 ip nat outside
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1318
 dialer in-band
 dialer idle-timeout 0
 dialer watch-group 1
 dialer-group 1
 ipv6 enable
 pulse-time 1

!Create the SLAs
! SLA for the fibre WAN
ip sla 1
 icmp-echo 8.8.8.8 source-interface gi0/0/0
 threshold 4000
 frequency 5
ip sla schedule 1 life forever start-time now
! SLA for fibre WAN
ip sla 2
 icmp-echo 139.130.4.4 source-interface gi0/0/0
 threshold 4000
 frequency 5
ip sla schedule 2 life forever start-time now
! SLA for 4G
ip sla 3
 icmp-echo 8.8.8.8 source-interface cellular0/2/0
 threshold 4000
 frequency 5
ip sla schedule 3 life forever start-time now
! SLA for 4G
ip sla 4
 icmp-echo 139.130.4.4 source-interface cellular0/2/0
 threshold 4000
 frequency 5
ip sla schedule 4 life forever start-time now

ip access-list extended PBR-SRC-ADDR-Traffic
 !Replace XXX with your WAN IP
 permit ip host XXX any

! Normally this would be a static IP 
ip access-list extended PBR-SRC-4G-Traffic
 permit ip host 192.168.0.100 any

 !The below is to ensure in event of the 4G interface being offline that the router will failback to the fibre internet connection
route-map PBR-SRC-ADDR permit 10
 description Route traffic with N1 source via Gi0/0/0
 match ip address PBR-SRC-ADDR-Traffic
 !Replace XXX with the gateway for your internet service 
 set ip next-hop XXX

! This will force traffic with 4G's source IP (usually static) to the next hop of the 4G Router.
! With this new LTE router the 4G is on Cellular 0/2/0 and the IP is unknown.
route-map PBR-SRC-ADDR permit 20
 description Route traffic with 4G source via 4G
 match ip address PBR-SRC-4G-Traffic
 set ip next-hop 192.168.0.1

! Make sure you set this AFTER the route-map exists, otherwise it doesn't apply.
ip local policy route-map PBR-SRC-ADDR

!Create the Tracking objects
track 1 ip sla 1
 delay down 20 up 10
track 2 ip sla 2
 delay down 20 up 10
track 3 ip sla 3
 delay down 20 up 10
track 4 ip sla 4
 delay down 20 up 10
track 5 list boolean or
 object 1
 object 2
track 6 list boolean or
 object 3
 object 4


!Replace xxx with Gateway IP of internet service
! Primary WAN
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 xxx 10 track 5
! 4G WAN
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Cellular0/2/0 15 track 6
! Primary WAN
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 xxx 20
! 4G WAN
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Cellular0/2/0 25
```